# Saving Visual Studio's Configuration Manager Settings Locally

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

would like to add my own configuration settings in Visual Studio 2010. I opened the configuration manager, created the profile I wanted and noticed that the settings are stored in the .csproj file. I would like to keep these settings local to my own box. Our source control currently checks in .csproj files and so if I checked these changes in, my entire team would be affected. Does anyone know if it's possible to create configuration settings that are local to your own dev box?

Edit: Adding a screenshot of the configuration manager. It's these settings I want to save locally.

[image: Configuration Manager]

Comment: what kind of settings do you want to keep?

Comment: I want to keep my active solution configuration settings. These are those settings that you can change when you do a build (debug is the default). I have several projects that add on quite a bit of build time and they never change. I have several configurations for excluding them from being built so only the project I am working in gets built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a `csproj` file and a `csproj.user` file.

Visual Studio places settings in the user file that can be different per user without affecting the entire team's development (like whether the Show All Files button is clicked). You wouldn't check this file in, and deleting it might be an inconvenience but it won't affect the program.

Visual Studio places settings in the csproj file itself that will affect your team's development (such as which classes are part of the project, references to DLLs, and the targeted framework version). You have to check this file in when changes are made, and deleting it would definitely affect your program.

This is based on my own understanding and experience. Maybe if you list which settings you'd like kept out of the csproj file, someone else on here will be able to list a workaround...

Answer (score 3):

Why not just save all this to a diffrenet solution file and use it, while others will use old one?